# python 3.9 magenta not working on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, magenta

I receive various error when trying to install magenta with pip

i get an error for building wheels for numba, llvmlite and python-rtmidi example for numba:

```
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rtmidi
      copying rtmidi\midiconstants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rtmidi
      copying rtmidi\midiutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rtmidi
      copying rtmidi\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rtmidi
      copying rtmidi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rtmidi
      running build_ext
      building 'rtmidi._rtmidi' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-rtmidi
  Running setup.py clean for python-rtmidi
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f301n_gf\llvmlite_52e74a978a1540339621403e230729a1\ffi\build.py
      -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.19044.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
        Failed to run MSBuild command:

          MSBuild.exe

        to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

          Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpjza6m78t/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
        Generator

          Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

        could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp0ap85972/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Trying generator 'Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64'
      Trying generator 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f301n_gf\llvmlite_52e74a978a1540339621403e230729a1\ffi\build.py", line 192, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f301n_gf\llvmlite_52e74a978a1540339621403e230729a1\ffi\build.py", line 180, in main
          main_win32()
        File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f301n_gf\llvmlite_52e74a978a1540339621403e230729a1\ffi\build.py", line 89, in main_win32
          generator = find_win32_generator()
        File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f301n_gf\llvmlite_52e74a978a1540339621403e230729a1\ffi\build.py", line 85, in find_win32_generator
          raise RuntimeError("No compatible cmake generator installed on this machine")
      RuntimeError: No compatible cmake generator installed on this machine
      error: command 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\anaconda3\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build numba python-rtmidi llvmlite
Installing collected packages: python-rtmidi, pygtrie, mido, llvmlite, keras, flatbuffers, tensorflow-estimator, sox, scipy, protobuf, promise, numba, keras-preprocessing, importlib_resources, imageio, etils, absl-py, tf-slim, tensorflow-probability, sk-video, resampy, mir-eval, matplotlib, googleapis-common-protos, dm-sonnet, tensorflow-metadata, librosa, tensorflow-datasets, tensorboard, note-seq, tensorflow, magenta
  Running setup.py install for python-rtmidi ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for python-rtmidi did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rtmidi
      copying rtmidi\midiconstants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rtmidi
      copying rtmidi\midiutil.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rtmidi
      copying rtmidi\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rtmidi
      copying rtmidi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\rtmidi
      running build_ext
      building 'rtmidi._rtmidi' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> python-rtmidi

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have no idea how to continue. Do you have a solution for this?

What we've found out is, that this issue is only appearing on windows but working on mac OS.

my python version is 3.9.13

Thank you very much!

tried to install magenta but receive errors

what I already tried and didn't work:

- reinstall all 3 packages
- downgrade versions of those packages
- the same with cmake and wheel package
- install windows sdk
- test it on another device

Comment: The error message clearly says `could not find any instance of Visual Studio.`. Which versions of Visual Studio do you have installed and where?

Comment: 'Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/'—there's a good starting point. Installed the Visual C++ Build Tools as instructed?